# OpenGL FBO depth format and type confusion

Tags: opengl, texture2d, fbo

I'm a bit confused about the internal format, format and type. So what's about the depth attachment point?

If I'm using a RenderBuffer, I think this is the valid code if I don't want to use stencil:

```
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRB);
```

However if I want to be able to read the depth values, I have to attach a texture to the depth attachment point. So I have to call a glTexImage2D function with parameters "internal format", "format" and "type".

In this case which internal format, format and type should I choose? Can I use the following combinations for a depth attachment? (in the order of: internal format, format and type)

- GL_R32F, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT
- GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_INT
- GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT

Is the GL_UNSIGNED_INT type valid for the 2nd case? What does that really mean? Will it allocate 4 bytes per fragment? In some tutorials they are using GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE for the type parameter. Which is the correct one?

Thanks

**Edit**:

Clarified my question about which parameters I'm interested in.

Comment: What do you mean, "format" and "type"? Renderbuffers have only an internal format, not an external one. Or are you asking which external format you should then use in a `glReadPixels` call?

Comment: According to Khronos Group reference pages You can only use the following as internal format of a render buffer: GL_RGBA4, GL_RGB565, GL_RGB5_A1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, or GL_STENCIL_INDEX8
[glRenderbufferStorage reference page](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRenderbufferStorage.xml)

Comment: @peppe i mean these parameters for the glTexImage2D function.

Comment: @Matso yea, I've seen that page but that is weird. It should be able to store at least one 32-bit format. And according to the [OpenGL spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) 9.2.5.:
"In addition, implementations are required to support the following sized and compressed internal formats [...] Depth, depth+stencil, and stencil formats which are checked in the “Req. format” column of table 8.13."

Comment: @csisy: "However if I want to be able to read the depth values, I have to attach a texture to the depth attachment point" this part is the one I was questioning -- read *how*? Also, for which OpenGL version specifically? For instance in ES2 you can't create a depth texture (and therefore attach one).

Comment: @peppe: oh, I see! I'm targeting desktop OpenGL 2.0 - so I'm using the glTexImage2D + glFramebufferTexture2D + glDrawBuffers combination

Comment: @csisy: If you're targeting OpenGL 2.0 (why?), then what extensions are you using that allow you to apply depth to a texture? Because that's not OpenGL 2.0 or GL 2.1 behavior. In fact, *renderbuffers* aren't 2.0 or 2.1. And you should put this vital information *in your question*, because it very much impacts the answer.

Comment: @peppe: "*What do you mean, "format" and "type"?*" He's talking about the pixel transfer parameters. The last three parameters to `glTexImage2D`.

Comment: @Matso The link you provide is to OpenGL ES documentation. OpenGL has many more supported formats.

Comment: @peppe: I'm using the [ARB_framebuffer_object](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_object.txt) extension. The whole FBO-system is not available without this in 2.0. However my question is about the texture storage parameters not the render buffer version. I'll update my question soon. :)

Comment: Reiterating the question from @peppe above: What do you mean by "read the depth values"? You can use `glReadPixels()` if the attachment is a renderbuffer. Do you mean that you want to sample the depth image in shader code?

Comment: @RetoKoradi sorry for not clarifying that question: yes I'd like to sample the depth texture in a shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth values are not color values. As such, if you want to store depth values in a texture, the texture must use an [internal format that contains depth information](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Depth_formats).

The [pixel transfer format/type](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) parameters, even if you're not actually passing data, must still be reasonable with respect to the internal format. Since the internal format contains depth information, your pixel transfer *format* must specify depth information: `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`.

As for the pixel transfer *type*, you should read `32F` back as `GL_FLOAT`.

Comment: This means that the 1st option in the OP is not valid (as I thought). I'm using the 3rd one now, but do I really have to choose that? I'll sample the texture in a shader. Is there any difference between the float-based and the integer-based version? And if I'm not using the float version (aka. *32F) which pixel transfer type should I choose?